# Ember.js Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'handler' of undefined

Tags: javascript, forms, ember.js, handlebars.js, dynamicform

I am trying to implement a dynamic form in Ember. I want the user to be able to select an option from a dropdown and add it to the form. Also each added field should have an "x" that deletes the element from the form.

I've put together something that seems to work [(JSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/CzbuM/3/) but whenever an added form element is deleted (the x next to it is clicked), I get an error in the console that says: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'handler' of undefined".

I think it may have something to do with the handlebars "action" helper that is attached to the "a" tag. I'm not sure though.

Here is a sample of the delete function that is called when the "x" next to the inserted input element is clicked.

```
        deleteOption: function (event) {
        this.removeChild(event);
        this.rerender();
        },
```

and here is the template for the "newOption" view that is used when a new input element is added (after clicking the "+" button)

```
    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="newOption">
    <p>
      <label {{bindAttr for="view.name"}}>{{view.label}}</label>
      <br /><input class="input-medium option" {{bindAttr id="view.name" name="view.name"}} type="text" maxlength="5"  />
      <a href="#" class="delete addsub" {{bindAttr id="view.name"}} {{action deleteOption view target="view.parentView" }}>X</a>
    </p>
  </script>
```

Comment: If you scroll down to almost the bottom of this page (https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1643) you'll see a post by "xtreme-topher-bullock" which gives a patch for the ember.js file, which takes care of this error. Also this error seemed to only be happening in Chrome. No idea why.